# Change the GIT root directory on a Windows computer

Tags: git, windows-console

I installed GIT on my windows computer a few days ago, and set the root directory to my user's folder (`c:/users/user`). It added some folders and files (such as `.git` and `.gitconfig`) to the user's folder and creates a bloated folder.

Now I'm interested in changing the root folder to an inner folder (which I'll name Programming).
Can I change the root directory without harming the repositories I already have? How can I do this from the console?

Comment: just move the folder

Comment: "set the root directory", you mean you created a repository there? You should make project-related repositories, not a big one for all your projects. In other words, you most likely want to create your git repositories inside subfolders of that Programming folder, one per project.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the .gitconfig in place (it is your global Git configuration)

But a `.git` subfolder means you have initialized a repository in `c:/users/user` (as in "`git init .`").
If you have added and committed all the files you need, you can:

- create a new root folder elsewhere.
- copy `c:/users/user/.git` in that new folder
- do a `git checkout HEAD -- .`
- if everything works, then delete `c:/users/user/.git` 
  That would move that repo in the new folder, and recreate its content.